# QuickBooks QBXML API Error: Failed to get an Interface ptr: Source: .\src\TimeActFilter.cpp

Tags: c++, quickbooks, intuit-partner-platform

My clients stumbled upon an issue when attempting to make a straightforward TimeTracking query utilizing two tools: OpenSync and QODBC.  They both present the same error in the qbsdklog.txt files.  Have any QBXML developers experienced this / devised a remedy?    Intuit general support has told them the fault lies with the 3rd party developers however I'm not sure how they came to such a conclusion.

QODBC:

```
20130913.095701 I   2588    QBSDKProcessRequest Application named 'FLEXquarters QODBC' starting requests (process 6920).
20130913.095701 I   2588    SpecVersion Current version of qbXML in use: 10.0
20130913.095701 I   2588    QBSDKMsgSetHandler  QUERY: Time Tracking
20130913.095701 I   2588    TimeTrackingStorage::DoQuery    Setting iterator chunk size to 00001000
20130913.100310 E   2588    TimeTrackingStorage::DoQuery    Failed to get an Interface ptr:  Source: .\src\TimeActFilter.cpp line #86 HRESULT=0x80004005
20130913.100310 I   2588    QBSDKMsgSetHandler  Request 1 failed.
20130913.100310 I   2588    MsgSetHandler   Finished.
```

OpenSync:

```
20130913.142336 I   2588    QBSDKProcessRequest Application named 'OpenSync' starting requests (process 700).
20130913.142336 I   2588    SpecVersion Current version of qbXML in use: 10.0
20130913.142336 I   2588    QBSDKMsgSetHandler  QUERY: Time Tracking
20130913.142336 I   2588    TimeTrackingStorage::DoQuery    Setting iterator chunk size to 2147483647
20130913.142337 E   2588    TimeTrackingStorage::DoQuery    Failed to get an Interface ptr:  Source: .\src\TimeActFilter.cpp line #86 HRESULT=0x80004005
20130913.142337 I   2588    QBSDKMsgSetHandler  Request  failed.
20130913.142337 I   2588 MsgSetHandler  Finished.
```

Any information is appreciated.

**Update**: Here is the XML request from OpenSync

```
<Trace>
<OUTGOING>
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="ISO-8859-1"?><QBXML><QBXMLMsgsRq onError = "continueOnError"><TimeTrackingQueryRq><ModifiedDateRangeFilter><FromModifiedDate>2013-09-12T22:22:59</FromModifiedDate><ToModifiedDate>2013-09-12T22:50:17</ToModifiedDate></ModifiedDateRangeFilter></TimeTrackingQueryRq></QBXMLMsgsRq></QBXML>
</OUTGOING>
<RETURNS>

<QBXML>
<QBXMLMsgsRs>
<TimeTrackingQueryRs statusCode="1" statusSeverity="Info" statusMessage="A query request did not find a matching object in QuickBooks" />
</QBXMLMsgsRs>
</QBXML>

</RETURNS>
</Trace>
```

Comment: What does the XML request you're sending to QuickBooks look like?

Comment: XML request added above.

Comment: Are there in fact TimeTracking entries within that date range that should be returned?

Comment: According to the client, yes.  Many.  If plotted on a timeline, the interface pointer error detailed in the log follows the XML request and proceeds the response so I feel as if it's safe to assume that why the return is empty.

Comment: If you remove the entire <ModifiedDateRangeFilter> node, do you get back any results? Can you post at least one of those results that shows a ModifiedTime within the time range specified? Honestly, what you're seeing doesn't indicate any sort of problem... it just looks like there aren't any time activity records that were modified within that 28 minute window.

Comment: This was initially brought to my attention because the client - after failing to refresh new/modified data - attempted to run a full population of the table (no filters).  This also came back empty.

You think the interface pointer error is merely coincidental?

Comment: FWIW - After running the SDKTestPlus3 tool I was able to confirm that the issue resides in the company file.  A clean time tracking query without filter returned an internal error.  All other queries worked fine.

Comment: Did you try verifying/rebuilding the company file data to see if that fixes it?

Comment: Yup.  Several times.  Had them reinstall QuickBooks and even load QB on a fresh PC.  No dice.